# How to convert Ionic mobile to web app

Tags: angularjs, html, web, web-applications, ionic-framework

Say I have an existing mobile app built on Ionic. Now I need to have a website version of the app so users can access it via desktop too. 
Is there any documentation that suggest this is possible?

Comment: Googling `How to convert Ionic mobile to web app` seems to yield loads of results, is none of them useful? Can you add some detail why?

Comment: I agree. I don't know if this is a valid question, and it's not something that can be answered in a SO way (imo).. you could just google and find a bunch. . 

Nevertheless, Ionic has been boasting about  Wassim Chegham's progressive web app built in Ionic 2. Here's the blog post http://blog.ionic.io/built-with-ionic-2-let-me-see/, and here is the source code https://github.com/manekinekko/angularattack2016.

Comment: There's plenty on web app to mobile. But not specifically any results on mobile to Web app.

Comment: Were you using Ionic 2?

Comment: Yeah the latest

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for Progressive Web Apps. Ionic does cater for such, just google for the term "Ionic PWA" example below.

http://blog.ionic.io/navigating-the-world-of-progressive-web-apps-with-ionic-2/

https://blog.saddey.net/2016/07/03/using-docker-to-create-ionic-2-pwa-developer-environment/